# Print Something Before Login

Tags: tty

In some distribution installers like Artix Linux Base or Manjaro Linux Architecture installers print a message before the login message. I want to do the same thing. How can I do the same for Linux and TTY?

Please don't mark as duplicate and don't answer as comment...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more context. What operating system are you using? Some Linux variant? Which one? Or maybe a UNIX? Which one? What kind of login? Local? Remote? Command line? GUI?

Comment: If your question is not a duplicate, I would expect you to refer to the question currently marked as a duplicate and say why that question+answer does not solve your issue.  It certainly _seems_ like a duplicate.  Also, does a Linux _installer_ usually allow you to log in? That bit in the question seems a bit confused.